# Python - Fast reg exps to replace repeated spaces in a delimited file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file delimited with ^F characters , i want to remove the extra white spaces in between the delimiters. Also i want to remove the appended zeros in the front . My file looks like this ,

File1.txt

```
12345^F0007564  ^F       ^F03^F           ^F01-18-2019 03:12:00  ^FAbcder   ^F
```

Expected Output :

```
12345^F7564^F^F3^F^F01-18-2019 03:12:00^FAbcder^F
```

File size is about 100mb with of 200k of records . Any fast approach to replace this and pass to data model using python 2.6.6 ?

Comment: Replace the spaces is pretty simple, about the `0`s, the one in `F01` should be replaced too?

Comment: `re.sub(r"(?<=^F)\s+(?=^F)", "", yourString)`

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want to remove all whitespace, or just all spaces?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: @Kevin  I want to remove all the repeated spaces before the delimiter and zero append in front the values . Also empty spaces between two delimiters.

Comment: @MatheusCuba : No, date format shouldn't be changed

Comment: Oh dear... If the code has to recognize that zeroes in a date should be left alone, that makes it much harder. It might even be impossible unless you know ahead of time where dates are likely to appear in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex in `re.sub`:

```
>>> text = '12345^F0007564  ^F       ^F03^F           ^F01-18-2019 03:12:00  ^FAbcder   ^F'
>>> print re.sub(r' {2,}|(?<=F)0+(?!\d+-)', '', text)
12345^F7564^F^F3^F^F01-18-2019 03:12:00^FAbcder^F
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5bHxiD/1/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `{2,}`: Match 2+ spaces
- `|`: OR
- `(?<=F)0+(?!\d+-)`: Match 1+ zeroes that have `F` before and not followed by 1+ digits and hyphen ahead (to avoid matching zeroes in dates)

Comment: Will give try for different positions .thanks

Comment: How about `12-18-2019`?

Comment: There are no zeroes to be removed in `12-18-2019` so it will remain same.

Answer (score 1):

This addresses the leading 0 in some dates:

```
input = "12345^F0007564  ^F       ^F03^F           ^F01-18-2019 03:12:00  ^FAbcder   ^F"
print(re.sub(r"(\^F)(0*(?!\d-))", '^F', input.replace(" ", "")))
```

Output:

```
12345^F7564^F^F3^F^F01-18-201903:12:00^FAbcder^F
```

**Edit:**

The above removes the space in the date. Another answer solves this by removing only double spaces or more, but assuming you want to remove ALL spaces besides those in date formatting, I'd actually break this into two `re.sub`'s:

```
input = "12345^F0007564  ^F       ^F03^F           ^F01-18-2019 03:12:00  ^FAbcder   ^F"
input = re.sub(r'(\^F)( )|( )\^F', '', input)
print(re.sub(r"(\^F)(0*(?!\d-))", '^F', input))
```

The first `re.sub` removes ALL space characters immediately before or after a `^F`. This is obviously less efficient than doing it with a single expression, but your data set isn't so large that it should be a concern.

Comment: Thanks .. Will have a check .

Comment: This is not giving correct output as it is stripping space after `2019`  a well.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, I missed that.  Edited.

Comment: Well, the issue isn't so much that you're using two `sub` calls, but more that the regex you use is unnecessarily confusing, and it is not easy to see what it is doing  by glancing at it.

Answer (score 0):

100mb is small. You can do this with any random regex you want.

```
import re

text = '12345^F0007564  ^F       ^F03^F           ^F01-18-2019 03:12:00  ^FAbcder   ^F'
print(re.sub(r'\s*\^F(((?!\d\d-)0*\s*)|\s*)', r'^F', text))
```

Here is a working [example](https://repl.it/repls/UnlawfulPotablePerimeter).

The output is correct: `12345^F7564^F^F3^F^F01-18-2019 03:12:00^FAbcder^F`.

The date is now left intact.